# Apiary - email parameter in URI definition, stopped working recently

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

In the last month or so, our Apiary API has broken. This is a major concern for us as our build keeps failing.

It seems to be something to do with parameters in our URI definition, requiring URL encoding.

E.g. for:

```
GET /user/{email}
```

nobody%40example.com is no longer working (404 error), but nobodyexample.com is.

I wonder if anything has recently changed on the Apiary side of things that might have caused this?

*Here is the whole blueprint:*

```
GET /user/v1/{email}
< 200
< Content-Type: application/atom+xml
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
            xmlns:u="urn:service:platform.user">
    <atom:id>http://jwps.apiary.io/user/v1/nobody%40example.com</atom:id>
    <atom:title>Professor Norman Body</atom:title>
    <u:title>Professor</u:title>
    <u:firstName>Norman</u:firstName>
    <u:lastName>Body</u:lastName>
    <u:emailAddress>nobody@example.com</u:emailAddress>
    <u:password>password</u:password>
    <u:status>enabled</u:status>
</atom:entry>
```

Comment: also worth noting that changing the definition to GET /user/nobody%40example.com works fine, but this is not ideal for us.

Comment: Looks like a regression. I have verified this. Will look into on Apiary side.

Comment: @khriskooper Can you provide us the whole part of that blueprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug and should be fixed now.